# no implementation found for method create on channel flutter/platform views

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, dart, flutter-method-channel

I'm adding flutter module into Android native application, this module contain google map, when the flutter module get initialized, it rout to flutter page but the map do not show.
when I debug I get this exception:

> MissingPluginException : no implementation found for method create on
> channel flutter/platform_views

this is Flutter code

```
class _TrackingMapsState extends State<TrackingMaps> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  static LatLng _initialPosition;
  Set<Marker> startedCircuitMarker = Set();
  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Localisation de Transport'),
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            setState(() {
              this._controller = controller;
            });
            // startMqttConnection();
          },
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          markers: startedCircuitMarker,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You just nee to close the app and execute 'flutter run' command.